# Java : Using wildcard (*) for a key of HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

What I'm tring to do is to create a HashMap,which looks like this.

[image]

I assumed that the wildcard symbol `*` can be used as a key, so if any character other than `a`,`b` and `c` (let's say `x`) is searched for, this HashMap will return `10`.

```
 for (int j = 0; j <= 2; j++) {            
        table.put(pattern[j], (pattern.length - 1 - j)); 
        //This part is actually not the same as the original code.
        //The keys are a,b,c, and the values are 1,2,3 respectively     
    }
    table.put('*', 10);
```

However, when I search this map for a key `x`, this returns `null`, so it is clear that `*` can't be directly used as a wildcard key. I followed [this page](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/57304/Use-wildcard-characters-and-to-compare-strings), but apparently this doesn't work for HashMap.

I'd appreciate if you would give any insight to solve this.

Comment: Subclass `HashMap` to make it do what you want, ie. given an value that isn't explicitly mapped, return `10`.

Comment: The `*` character is not special in HashMaps. HashMaps operate _only_ on the hashCode and equality of their keys -- there is no other magic (other than `null`, I guess, which is special cased to be equal only to itself). There's no more reason for `*` to act like a wildcard than there is for, say, `w` or `☃` to act as wildcards.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis But that would break the contract for `Map`.

Comment: @PaulBoddington Nah, just clarify the behavior in the specification for this new class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java 1.8 support getOrDefault

So u can use map.getOrDefault(key,defaultValue)

Comment: Thank you for your advice, but apparently there isn't a method which can set the default value, is there?

Comment: I'm reading this (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#getOrDefault-java.lang.Object-V-)

Comment: If there is no such a method, I'd override the `getOrdefault(key,defaultValue)` so that I can set the default value. How do you think about this idea?

Comment: You can do that. But the better design , as I think , is to put the default value as a property in the class that uses the map

Comment: Thank you so much. I feel like I learned a lot from it.

Answer (score 0):

It's best to just treat it separately, rather than create a new Map class.
You could do something like this with some wrapper class:

```
public Object getWithDefault(key){
    if (hashMap.get(key) == null){
        return hashMap.get("*");
    }
}
```

Then call it with the wrapper class

```
wrapper.getWithDefault('d');  // returns 10.
```